# Maintaining a css :hover effect for all items up a nested list chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I have DOM that looks like this:

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
  <li>
    <a>OuterMenu</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>InnerMenu1</a>
        <ul><li><a>InnerMenu2</a></li><li><a>Item 1</a></li><li><a>Item 2</a></li></ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

which looks like this:

```
+Hello              +OuterMenu
                    ----InnerMenu1--------------InnerMenu2
                    ----Other list item         Item 1
                                                Item 2
```

That is, the first menu is horizontal, the next menu is directly below the first menu, and all subsequent inner menus appear directly to the right [[see example here](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/create-a-multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-css-and-improve-it-via-jquery)].

This works fine, but I need the hover styles for each outer menu to persist as each inner menu is selected. When the user is hovering over `Item 1`, `Item 1`, `InnerMenu`, and `OuterMenu` should be highlighted, and when the user moves off of the whole menu tree, then and only then should `OuterMenu` no longer be highlighted. Is there a better way to do this than trying to manage a `hover` and `mouseout` event on every single list item?

I'm looking for a clean implementation here.

Comment: Also, if mouseout is the only good solution, how do I detect when the mouse is outside of *every* element in the menu graph?

Comment: This should all be doable with CSS and :hover — the hover event "bubbles" up the DOM tree to these elements, so you would still maintain your state while hovering on subelements of the top-level LI.

Comment: (However, you might want to consider JS, because you'll be able to add hover-intent timeouts that prevent users from accidentally losing the menu when they mouse out completely. Again, you can bind all your JS events to the top-level LI, because events on sub-elements will bubble up to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t know what you have already, but if you use something like:

```
#nav > li:hover > a {
    // outer menu highlight
}
```

it should highlight the outer menu also when you are on a sub-menu item.

The same technique can be applied to all levels, but it depends on your browser compatibility requirements as `li:hover` will not work in older IE versions.

**For completeness**

```
/* second level */
#nav > li > ul > li:hover > a {
}
/* third level */
#nav > li > ul > li > ul > li:hover > a {
}
```

Comment: I need IE7 compatibility, unfortunately.

Comment: But I might be able to replicate this in an IE js fix...Hmm.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall It seems that IE7 supports `:hover` on all elements so no IE fix is needed: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: That's not what my testing seems to confirm. Could be a doctype issue, but I can't change that.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall That´s strange, I´ve got it working in IE7 compatibility mode in an old site with doctype `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: Actual IE7 doesn't respect li:hover, even with that doctype. IE8 doesn't honor it *without* that doctype. I had to upgrade the doctype to test all this. I wanted more usable menus in the end anyway, so I had to use a bit of javascript (to prevent the menus from insta-closing, for example).

Answer (score 2):

Check out Stu Nicholls [great css-only work](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/dd_valid.html) on just this issue.

Comment: Looks promising. This is my exact layout configuration, and the behavior is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Simply using the `:hover` psuedo-class on your `li` will apply even when you are over a descendant element. Here's a working example showing that this is true: http://jsfiddle.net/eMyHE/; hover over InnerMenu2 and you'll see InnerMenu1 and OuterMenu highlight.

Also, you might be interested in my 8-years-old [CSS-only hierarchical menu tests](http://phrogz.net/JS/ul2menu/purecss_testsuite.html), part of some ancient code that uses [JavaScript for hierarchical menus](http://phrogz.net/JS/ul2menu/).

Comment: The innermenus aren't truly *within* the `<li>`. They're beside it, floated with absolute positioning.

Comment: My real issue is getting over ie's reluctance to support li:hover.

Comment: @StefanKendall If they are within it from a markup perspective, they are within it as far as 'hover' is concerned.

Comment: @StefanKendall What version(s) of IE are you having trouble with? See the last link in my answer for simple JS + CSS that I wrote to make things work nicely with IE6 way back in the day.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't my work, I'm just passing it on.  It looks like it's the same answer as JakeParis's, but in JSFiddle form. http://jsfiddle.net/XPE3w/7/  This is for HTML with a ul>li>a structure (see the link if this doesn't make sense).

```
ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #2C5463;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background: #617F8A;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a {
    background: #617F8A;
}
li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #95A9B1;
}
```